# Simulating flt format rasters or grids

Tags: r, raster

I am simulating a series of spatial grids filled with environmental data taken from  the field uses the code below. As these spatial grids are not simulating an actual point in space I have not defined any factors such as coordinate system, etc. However, I now need to feed these spatial grids into the `gdmEngine::TransformGrids()` function which requires them to be in .flt format.  I am completely unfamiliar with this format type, though from my searching it appears to be a standard ESRI file type. However, through my searching I have not been able to figure out how to define a raster as being .flt format and would greatly appreciate any assistance with this.

The code I am using to simulate the spatial grids is:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)

install_github("cwarecsiro/gdmEngine/gdmEngine")
library(gdmEngine)

library(dplyr)
library(raster)
library(gdm)

## Create some example data
lt_list <- sample(c(1, 2, 3), 100, TRUE)
lt_map <- raster(matrix(lt_list, 10, 10))
lt_map[lt_map==3] <- "F"
lt_map[lt_map==2] <- "R"
lt_map[lt_map==1] <- "O"

ID <- c("F", "R", "O", "O", "R", "F", "F", "O", "R", "R")
A <- runif(10,0,10)
B <- runif(10,0,5)
C <- runif(10,0,15)

df <- data.frame(cbind(ID, A, B, C))

## My actual function
Create_Rasters <- function(variable_name, lt_map. = lt_map, df. = df){
  ## Make an empty dataframe with the same dimensions as the ltmap
  df_var_mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = NROW(lt_map.), ncol = NCOL(lt_map.))

  ## Select appropriate environmental values based on land use
  for (x in 1:NROW(df_var_mat)){
    for (y in 1:NCOL(df_var_mat)){
      land_use = as.matrix(lt_map.)[x,y]

      values_list <- df. %>%
        dplyr::filter(., ID == land_use) %>%
        dplyr::select(., variable_name)

      ## Choose a random value from the list
      df_var_mat[x,y] <- values_list[runif(1, 1, NROW(values_list)),]
    }
  }

  df_var_raster <- raster(df_var_mat)

  return(df_var_raster)
}

env_grids_list <- map(c("A", "B", "C"), 
                  Create_Rasters, lt_map. = lt_map, df. = df)

env_stack <- stack(env_grids_list)
```

Comment: So you need to write the raster you are creating in the script above to disk in the .flt format?

Comment: @JacobF currently I do not need to write the raster out to disk, I need to use it in R in the `gdmEngine::TransformGrids()` function.

Comment: I don't see a gdmEngine package on CRAN. Also you would need to include library calls for any otehr package as well as installation instructions for the non-CRAN pkgs.

Comment: Perhaps useful: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2013-April/018176.html

Comment: The function doesn't require them to be in that format, however I see in the documentation it has an example that assumes they are in that format when being read from disk. The format it is stored on disk as doesn't necessarily matter to most functions or packages as long as it can be read in by the raster package.

Comment: @JacobF while the documentation does not mention requiring any particular format when I run the function using a raster stack built using my code above as such `gdmEngine::TransformGrids(gdm.model = birds_gdm,
                                  env.grids.stk = env_rstack,
                                  extrap.method = "Conservative",
                                  output.folder = "Outputs")`
I get the following error message:
`Error in gdmEngine::TransformGrids(gdm.model = birds_gdm, env.grids.stk = env_rstack,  : 
  env grids need to be in .flt format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code for the package it checks for the format of the file on disk that was used to create `env_stack`. Since you generated the stack it is only stored in memory. You will have to write the contents of `env_stack` to disk and then read it back in.

```
writeRaster(env_stack, 'env_stack.flt', format='EHdr')
env_stack <- stack('env_stack.flt')
#You may need to set the layer names in the stack to match the predictors in your model
names(env_stack) <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
TransformGrids(gdm.model = birds_gdm, env.grids.stk = env_rstack, extrap.method = "Conservative", output.folder = "Outputs")
```

Comment: Thanks @Jacob F that solution seems to work at getting around my issue.